# Dynamically order <dt>

Tags: javascript, html

I have description list like this,

```
<dl>
  <dt>Coffee</dt>
    <dd>Black hot drink</dd>
  <dt>Milk</dt>
    <dd>White cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

The output is like below,

```
Coffee
    Black hot drink
Milk
    White cold drink
```

Now I need to Change the order of this list dynamically, For example, When clicking a button the order should be changed like below,

```
Milk
    White cold drink 
Coffee
    Black hot drink
```

Any idea how to do this? Is it possible to do this in Javascript?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Dynamically generate the <dl> and <dt> tags and append it to some div then show that div.it will be done.

Comment: you want to order it but in what fashion? ie: ascending ,descending ,random

Comment: You can either sort on the web server before or as the `HTML` is being created, or using `JavaScript` on the client. Is the `HTML` generated by any server-side language or is it just plain `HTML`?

Comment: Hi All, It is plain HTML, NOT dynamically created one. So the order given in HTML is shown on first time. Then once the button clicked, the order should be changed. The order should be random, probably rotating order Assume if <dt>s 1 2 3 4 5 then it should be changed to 2 3 4 5 1. Some thing like this.. Since it's not dynamically created list, any javascript solution can help me.

Comment: This is really markup dependant, and as it is in the example, with no nesting and a clear structure, something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/cnxe9/) would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same with `JavaScript` . Take a look [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/5vxn4/1/)

JS:

```
function change()
{
    for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByTagName("dt").length-1;i++) 
   {
     var a=document.getElementsByTagName("dt")[i].innerHTML;
     var aa=document.getElementsByTagName("dd")[i].innerHTML;
     var b=document.getElementsByTagName("dt")[i+1].innerHTML;
     var bb=document.getElementsByTagName("dd")[i+1].innerHTML;
     document.getElementsByTagName("dt")[i].innerHTML=b;
     document.getElementsByTagName("dd")[i].innerHTML=bb;
     document.getElementsByTagName("dt")[i+1].innerHTML=a;
     document.getElementsByTagName("dd")[i+1].innerHTML=aa;
    }
}
```